# Exterior power of a torsion-free sheaf on a DVR

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, flatness, exterior-algebra

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring and $X$ be a regular, integral. projective $R$-scheme, flat over $R$. Let $F$ be a torsion-free coherent sheaf on $X$ of rank $n$, flat over $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$. Is there any known additional conditions on $X$ under which we can conclude that the exterior power $\wedge^n F$ is again flat over $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. Isn't it always flat?

Comment: @Ron Flatness of an $R$-integral domain  $A$ over a dvr $R$ is automatic when $R\to A$ is injective.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar I do not quite follow. Are you saying as well that it is always flat? Could you please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger As in your other answer, here as well the wedge product is not taken as $R$-modules. Do you still this it is always flat?

Comment: @Ron: I still don't see why it shouldn't be. Do you have an example where it isn't?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger No, I do not have any such example. Could you please given an argument or hint, why you think it should be possible.

Comment: Here is an example where $\Lambda^nF$ is not $R$-flat: Assume, say, $\dim X=2$ and let $x$ be a closed point (in the closed fiber). Let $I\subset\mathscr{O}_X$ be the ideal sheaf of $x$, which is torsion-free of rank $1$ on $X$. Observe that $\Lambda^2I$ is nonzero and supported at $x$. Now take $F=I\oplus\mathscr{O}_X$: then  $\Lambda^2F$ contains  $\Lambda^2I$ as a direct summand, hence it has $R$-torsion.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Thank you very much for the example. Is there any conditions when we have an affirmative answer to the question, that you know of? The example I had in mind was when $F$ was of a semistable sheaf.

Comment: what do you mean by "the wedge product is not taken as $R$-modules"?

Comment: @WillSawin I mean the wedge product in my case is the tensor product $F \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} ... \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} F$ modulo the usual equivalence relations and not $F \otimes_R ... \otimes_R F$ modulo equivalence.

Comment: @Ron Ok, then I think Laurent's example will cause you trouble basically unless $X$ is zero-dimensional.